# How can I make a Python function return only one of two values when using DataFrame.apply?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apply

If I use this fuction `line1.apply(sc.shapiro, axis=1)`.
it gives me the result like this `(0.9815108776092529, 0.9715939164161682)`. 
I want to get only the **second** value, so I tried to write it like this 
`line1.apply(sc.shapiro[1], axis=1)` but it never worked :(

The problem is

```
----> 1 line1.apply(sc.shapiro[1], axis=1) 

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: line1.apply(sc.shapiro, axis=1)[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to slice out the `[1]` from the actual result, not the method argument: `line1.apply(sc.shapiro, axis=1)[1]`. And since your input argument is a function, that also explains your error message.